# Two components individually managing their own state and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering two Dropdown components (custom) side by side.
They both have the same initial status: All Statuses, and then render individual views. I want them to manage their own state and props and only share methods. Somehow there is some weirdness of sharing props. I click to change one status and get it reflected in the other component.

See CodeSandbox Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-wood-cf8u8?file=/src/App.js

Can you see how to make them unique and separate from one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two selects are sharing HTML id attributes - specifically the ones used by htmlFor.

If you pass in a name prop so that it's different for each Dropdown and pass that through to the DropdownView you should be able to make the radio input 'id's and label 'htmlFor's unique.

Comment: Better yet, generate a uuid for each ID attribute, and encapsulate the need for unique IDs from consumers of the component

Comment: @ben-stephens care to show an example of what you mean? I updated the code to what I believe you mean, but I'm still not certain

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-cannon-ejry5 Edit: Sorry, it looks like I didn't save something. Edit2: saved